# lz4: what is the max ultra-fast compression level?

Tags: lz4

From `man lz4`:

```
--fast[=#]
       Switch  to ultra-fast compression levels. The higher the value, the faster the compres‐
       sion speed, at the cost of some compression ratio. If =# is not present, it defaults to
       1.  This setting overrides compression level if one was set previously. Similarly, if a
       compression level is set after --fast, it overrides it.
```

So what is the max ultra-fast compression level? Is it the same (12) as for compression level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s currently 65537, as determined by [the `LZ4_ACCELERATION_MAX` constant](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/e3974e5a1476190afdd8b44e67106cfb7097a1d5/lib/lz4.c#L54).

See also [the library documentation for “fast” compression](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/e3974e5a1476190afdd8b44e67106cfb7097a1d5/doc/lz4_manual.html#L144).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the command line [source code](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/programs/lz4cli.c), the compression level is set to the negative of the `--fast=#` number; this is the only use of this number. As you said the max compression level is 12 so, while I can't be 100% certain that there is symmetry here, it could be that the max effective fast number is also 12.